Find if word exists between two words and replace that word in JavaScript
I have something like:
Some MY_WORD stupid txt='other text MY_WORD' and another MY_WORD  stupid text and txt='something else MY_WORD' and also txt='here nothing to replace' and here txt='again to replace MY_WORD here'

I want to replace MY_WORD with OTHER_WORD but only if it is inside txt=' and '
/(?<=txt='.*)MY_WORD(?=.*')/g


Some MY_WORD stupid txt='other text OTHER_WORD' and another MY_WORD  stupid text and txt='something else OTHER_WORD' and also txt='here nothing to replace' and hexe txt='again to replace OTHER_WORD here'

But look behind is not supported in all browsers, so it is not good approach.
A tried with this but even it says there are groups of matches, I $3 is empty.
(txt=')((\.*)(MY_WORD))?


which browser doesn't support the look behind?

I suppose it might be even harder to find if you allowed escaping of your single quotes.  E.g.:  txt='it\'s MY_WORD o\'clock'

@AlexanderNenashev, I read somewhere, probably some older browser so if I can achieve to work with as much as possible browser I will take that :)

Old browsers you are speaking about represent a marginal market share and all recent browsers are freely downloadable. So the way to go is not to write a crappy workaround, but to correct your pattern with lookarounds. Note that, well written, this pattern is the fastest solution: /MY_WORD(?<=txt='[^']*)(?=[^']*')/g.

You can match the text between txt=' and ' using a simple txt='[^']*' regex. Then, upon finding the matches, replace all occurrences of MY_WORD with what you need inside an arrow function:
text.replace(/txt='[^']*'/g, (x) => x.replace(/MY_WORD/g, 'NEW_WORD'))

where x stands for the whole match.
See the JavaScript demo:


var text = "Some MY_WORD stupid txt='other text MY_WORD' and another MY_WORD  stupid text and txt='something else MY_WORD' and also txt='here nothing to replace' and here txt='again to replace MY_WORD here'";
console.log( text.replace(/txt='[^']*'/g, (x) => x.replace(/MY_WORD/g, 'NEW_WORD')) );




What is faster, this approach or (/(txt\s*=\s*'[^']*)\bMY_WORD\b/g, $1OTHER_WORD)

@user1182625 Please never compare pears to oranges. My code replaces all occurrences in between two strings, the one you mentioned only replaces one. Certainly, using an arrow function in the replacement makes the code execute slower, as it does more than just a plain regex replace. "It is what it is", just use what suits you most. I understood there can be multiple occurrences between two strings, else, I do not understand why you used lookarounds in the first place.

I first gave this simple regex pattern:
/(txt\s*=\s*'[^']*)\bMY_WORD\b/g

But then later thought "But what happens if MY_WORD is several
times in the string content?"
This means you'll have to do it in two steps:

Search for all strings, and also handle possible simple quotes
inside the strings themselves (let's say escaped with a
backslash).

Search for the full word MY_WORD and not only this string.


So, first regex:
/(txt\s*=\s*')((?:\\.|[^'\\])*)'/g

We look for txt followed by an equal sign, optionally having
spaces around it. Then look for either a backslash followed by any
char or any char which is not a backslash, neither a simple quote.
Once we've found all the txt = '...' then we search for all
occurrences of the full word, using word boundaries with the use
of \b.
Full JS working example where you can change the input to test it:


const REGEX_STRING = /(txt\s*=\s*')((?:\\.|[^'\\])*)'/g;
const REGEX_WORD = /\bMY_WORD\b/g;
const NEW_WORD = 'OTHER_WORD';

// When the document is ready, attach the event handlers.
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  const input = document.getElementById("input");
  const output = document.getElementById("output");

  function updateOutput() {
    output.value = input.value.replace(
      REGEX_STRING,
      (match, txtEqual, strContent) => {
        return txtEqual + strContent.replace(REGEX_WORD, NEW_WORD) + "'";
      }
    );
  }
  
  // Each change in the input textarea should update the output textarea.
  input.addEventListener('input', onlyOnceAtATime(updateOutput));
  
  // When clicking in the output textarea, select all the text.
  output.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    const target = event.target;
    target.setSelectionRange(0, target.value.length);
  });
  
  // For the first load, calculate the output.
  updateOutput();
});

/**
 * This function is used to call a specific function callback only once
 * at the time. This is to avoid multiple events such as 'input' to run
 * multiple times and lead to a non-responding browser.
 *
 * @param {function} callback The function to call.
 */
function onlyOnceAtATime(callback) {
  // Keep track of all the running callbacks.
  let runningCallbacks = new Map();

  return function (...args) {
    if (runningCallbacks.has(callback.name)) {
      return;
    }

    runningCallbacks.set(callback.name, true);
    callback(...args);
    runningCallbacks.delete(callback.name);
  };
}
.form-element {
  margin: 1em 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

label {
  padding-bottom: .2em;
  
  &::after {
    content: " :";
  }
}

textarea[readonly] {
  background: silver;
}
<form action="#">
  <div class="form-element">
    <label for="input">Input</label>
    <textarea name="input" id="input" cols="80" rows="4">Some MY_WORD stupid txt='MY_WORD and MY_WORD or \'Hello\'' and another MY_WORD stupid text txt = 'something else MY_WORD' and also txt='here nothing to replace' and here txt='again to replace MY_WORD here but not DUMMY_WORD'</textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="form-element">
    <label for="output">Output with <code>MY_WORD</code> replaced by <code>OTHER_WORD</code></label>
    <textarea name="output" id="output" cols="80" rows="4" readonly></textarea>
  </div>
</form>




I reuse this, replaceAll("/(txt\s*=\s*'[^']*)\bMY_WORD\b/g","$1OTHER_WORD"), thnx :)

@user1182625 : I updated my answer, because we have to handle multiple occurrences of the word in the string, and also better take in consideration the fact that you may have some quotes inside your strings!

I agree, but in my case I create that text, and MY_WORD can appear only once inside txt='....MY_WORD'. I use this to replace the user ID with a full name once async gives a result or I have it already in the cache :)

@user1182625 Ok, I see. Well, if you just want to handle simple quotes inside the string itself, then it would become /(txt\s*=\s*'(?:\\.|[^'\\])*)\bMY_WORD\b/g. In action here: https://regex101.com/r/mpPB9C/1

I have only one MY_WORD inside txt='...', ok, maybe to have also anything after MY_WORD before '

Since you need only 1 replacement inside the quotes, it will faster than replace multiple words:


const str = "Some MY_WORD stupid txt='other text MY_WORD' and another MY_WORD  stupid text and txt='something else MY_WORD' and also txt='here nothing to replace' and here txt='again to replace MY_WORD here'";

const result = str.replace(/(txt='[^']*)MY_WORD/g, '$1OTHER_WORD');

console.log(result);



If you need maximum speed you can replace words manually inside quotes:


const str = "Some MY_WORD stupid txt='other text MY_WORD' and another MY_WORD  stupid text and txt='something else MY_WORD' and also txt='here nothing to replace' and here txt='again to replace MY_WORD here and MY_WORD again '";

function replaceWordInQuotes(str, word, replace){
  const len = word.length;
  let result = '', insideQuotes = false, quoteIdx = 0, prevIdx = 0;
  while(true){
    const i = str.indexOf("'", quoteIdx);
    if(i < 0) break;
    if(insideQuotes){
      const wi = str.indexOf(word, quoteIdx);
      if(wi < 0) break;
      if(wi < i){
        result += str.slice(prevIdx, wi) + replace;
        prevIdx = wi + len;
        quoteIdx = wi + len;
        continue;
      }
    }
    insideQuotes = !insideQuotes;
    quoteIdx = i + 1;
  }

  result += str.slice(prevIdx);
  return result;
}

console.log(replaceWordInQuotes(str, 'MY_WORD', 'OTHER_WORD'));



Benchmarking 3 options:
` Chrome/125
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Alexander manual replace        ■ 1.00x | x1000000 214 216 223 232 234
Alexander 1 word replace regex    1.46x | x1000000 312 314 319 336 342
Wiktor Stribiżew regex            2.69x | x1000000 575 588 606 619 627
---------------------------------------------------------------------- `

Open in the playground


const str = "Some MY_WORD stupid txt='other text MY_WORD' and another MY_WORD  stupid text and txt='something else MY_WORD' and also txt='here nothing to replace' and here txt='again to replace MY_WORD here and MY_WORD again '";

function replaceWordInQuotes(str, word, replace){
  const len = word.length;
  let result = '', insideQuotes = false, quoteIdx = 0, prevIdx = 0;
  while(true){
    const i = str.indexOf("'", quoteIdx);
    if(i < 0) break;
    if(insideQuotes){
      const wi = str.indexOf(word, quoteIdx);
      if(wi < 0) break;
      if(wi < i){
        result += str.slice(prevIdx, wi) + replace;
        prevIdx = wi + len;
        quoteIdx = wi + len;
        continue;
      }
    }
    insideQuotes = !insideQuotes;
    quoteIdx = i + 1;
  }

  result += str.slice(prevIdx);
  return result;
}

// @benchmark Alexander manual replace
replaceWordInQuotes(str, 'MY_WORD', 'OTHER_WORD');

// @benchmark Alexander 1 word replace regex
str.replace(/(txt='[^']*)MY_WORD/g, '$1OTHER_WORD');

// @benchmark Wiktor Stribiżew regex 
str.replace(/txt='[^']*'/g, (x) => x.replace(/MY_WORD/g, 'OTHER_WORD'))

/*@skip*/ fetch('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js').then(r => r.text().then(eval));




why have you answered this question three times (deleting two of them), with the final being effectively a duplicate of Wiktor Stribiżew's answer?

@pilchard it's not a duplicate, look closer, i don't use a replace callback

I need for all founded :)

@user1182625 i've added a benchmark to compare 2 solutions

I understand the question of speed and it's always a good point to consider. But I often think that unhandled input is more often the problem. What happens if the input is txt =  'spaces before' or if it contains simple quotes in the string itself, like txt='Say \'Hello World!\' and DUMMY_WORD should not be replaced by DUMOTHER_WORD'

@PatrickJanser i guess the input is pretty restricted in this case... there's no mentions of free white space number

@AlexanderNenashev Yes, you are certainly right! I'm probably so used to end user making special cases that I tend to think too far and get into complicated routines. Thanks for sharing the benchmarking tools, it's very interesting! :-)

@PatrickJanser this text I created otherwise I agree with you completely. The idea is to show HTML right away with USER_ID and to have an async function to get the full name from the service if USER_ID with full name is not already in the session cache or to replace it from the cache if it is there.
